# how to design application architecture in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I am going to convert Visual C# application into ASP.NET. For this task, I want to create architecture first and then want to develop programme. So, how can I break-down my logic into libraries? I know, its very basic question, but very much worried about it as I am working alone and I need assistance..

Comment: I think link help you.http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article71.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this [Building Layered Web Applications with Microsoft ASP.NET](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/416/building-layered-web-applications-with-microsoft-aspnet-20-part-1)  as a model when i started building web applications using ASP.Net

Answer (score 1):

With any luck your existing application has been written using SOLID OO principles. In this case you can separate your business logic from your UI. If this is not the case then I would start by making a clean set of interfaces to your business logic and make some unit tests around them. The next thing is MVC is optimized for disconnect situations such as web applications. Depending on what infrastructure you have create either an MVC3 or and MVC4 application using Razor and test projects. As you build out your project try to make unit tests as you go. This will improve the reliability of your code, also switch on the FxCop static code analysis. The next thing you will need to think about is how interactive you want your web UI to be. If your users are intranet users perhaps you could get away with using the scaffolding features with the data annotations in the model. If your application is to impress external customers then you need a richer user experience. In which case look into making an MVVM pattern on your client browser using knockout. Here is a link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/305308/MVC-Techniques-with-JQuery-JSON-Knockout-and-Cshar

As you build the controllers there is a tendency for them to become fat (it’s a consequence of SRP) Think about using techniques such as aspect orientated programming with compiler attributes and filters to keep the code dry and clean.

A lot of what you need to do will depend on your organization. For example if you are working in an organization with SOA policies then you will need to discuss with your architects how you want to use WebAPI vs WCF. Another aspect to think about is how will Microsoft support client side scripting in the future. At a guess I am hoping that they will make tooling to simplify the javascripting side. For the time being I am learning HTML5 with javascript libraries like Jquery,Jquery-Ui, Ajax  in order to make a richer user experience

I hope this helps…

Comment: Your answer really helps me to understand my problem.. But one think is what to use MVC or 3/N- Tier architecture? As, I am new programmer, I have some experience handy to develop Web Forms, but I don't have any idea about MVC Pattern(Knowing the concept but not how to do coding).   
  
I have read many article for what to choose: Web Forms or MVC? In Conclusion I summarized that its not important what you use, but it should complete your job..  
  
Can you help me regarding that?

Comment: There is a learning curve arround MVC, but it is worthwhile because your code will be more maintainable and the skill that you learn will be applicable in other projects. If you have problems you can still add aspx files to your MVC project, not that I would recommend this because it breaks the MVC pattern. Take an agile approach and address the risky things first and "fail early" (hopefully not at all). Take a sample MVC demo and progressively modify to look like how your application should look like. If you find it does not work you can revert back to your old style of programming.